How to generate a masked image in vtk
I am trying to create a mask on vtk in a particular shape sample image.
I managed to create the shape using lines nd splines. I want the mask to be created using the shape i created.
    appendFilterus->AddInputData(line1->GetOutput());
    appendFilterus->AddInputData(line2->GetOutput());
    appendFilterus->AddInputData(spline_source->GetOutput()); 
    appendFilterus->AddInputData(spline_source2->GetOutput());
    appendFilterus->Update();

I tried using vtkImageCanvasSource2D , but it allows only some predefined shapes.
How can i create this mask? Is it possible to create using vtkImageCanvasSource2D itself ? Am i missing something ?
